# Converting snake_case to PascalCase

Tags: php, regex

Is there an effective way, maybe with regex, to change the following text pattern?

I have a string like `abc_def_ghi_jkl`. I want to replace it to `AbcDefGhiJkl`.  I currently use the following code to change it. Is there a more effective way than this?

```
implode('',array_map('ucfirst',explode('_',$string)));
```

Comment: What you describe is usually called PascalCase.

Answer (score 26):

More effective solution:

```
str_replace('_', '', ucwords($key, '_'));
```

From [Gears library](https://github.com/Cosmologist/Gears/blob/master/src/Gears/Str/CamelSnakeCase.php)

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  Why is this solution more effective?

Comment: Because, array_map is expensive operation

Comment: Here's a test that proves the above point: https://repl.it/ERrZ/6 (For the lazy: `array_map`: 575ms, `str_replace`: 365ms). Suggestion: Add more of an explanation next time :-)

Comment: Why not `str_replace('_', '', ucwords($key, '_'))`? It is faster and code shorter by setting delimiter directly in ucwords

Comment: @aokaddaoc, good solution!

Answer (score 3):

I know, its not the latest question, but here is another solution.

Not really pretty, but works well, is in one line and has a better performance than the solution in the question: `str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace(['-', '_'], ' ', $str)))`

BTW. here are some `microtime` results from my server:

```
// 9.0599060058594E-6
// 
$result = implode('',array_map('ucfirst',explode('_',$string)));

// 4.2915344238281E-5
// 
$result = preg_replace_callback("/(?:^|_)([a-z])/", function($matches) {
  return strtoupper($matches[1]);
}, $string);

// 5.0067901611328E-6
// 
$result = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace(['-', '_'], ' ', $string)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `preg_replace_callback()`, which replaces matches with the result of a function:

```
$str = "abc_def_ghi_jkl";
$str = preg_replace_callback("/(?:^|_)([a-z])/", function($matches) {
//       Start or underscore    ^      ^ lowercase character
    return strtoupper($matches[1]);
}, $str);
echo $str;
```

Whichever works for you, your solution is fine as well.